# Why are C# ticks similar for a Binary Search function with known performance differences?

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, binary

So I'm trying to graph the performance of Binary Search, using both arrays with and without findable keys.

It is known that Binary Search on an array with a present key is: log_2(n)-1.

And without: log_2(n)+1.

I've written an array generator function, and used a textbook version of Binary Search that I've implemented in C#. I've placed a Stopwatch object in the class, called 'sw'. arrayCreator takes true/false for determining if a key should be present. The key is stored globally.

My main looks like this, where i is used to increase the number of items in its array output, and true/false sets the global key either to a value present or not in the array (this will hopefully increase time which I'll measure).

```
for (int i = 500; i <= 50000; i += 500)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
    {
        int[] arrayCreated = arrayCreator(i, true);
        sw.Start();
        BinarySearch(arrayCreated, key);
        sw.Stop();
    }

    ticks = sw.ElapsedTicks;
    sw.Reset();
    Console.WriteLine(ticks);
    ticks = 0;
}
```

However, when I change my `arrayCreator` function to `true` or `false` the number of ticks doesn't really change much.

Is it possible to measure an algorithm like this? I've counted operations, and that confirmed the known results, but this won't. Is it possible that very system intensive functions like my arrayCreator (which is incredibly inefficient) are impacting on the results?

Comment: How could we possibly know whether the time it takes to complete `arrayCreator` will go up or down by passing `false` instead of `true` if you did not post what that function does? Also, that's not the number of *ticks*, it's the number of *milliseconds*

Comment: Do you expect there to be a measurable difference between `O(log(n) - 1)` and `O(log(n) + 1)` as n grows to large sets?  I do not.

Comment: Binary search is O(log2(n)).  Odds that it is faster are only high if it can find the key while still busy narrowing the search range.  That will only happen when there are many copies of key.  Crystal ball says that is not what your arrayCreator() method does.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, oh I'm not measuring the time it takes to complete arrayCreator. I said that in my question. Binary Search is well known — you can find it on the internet. arrayCreator works when I measure the number of operations — its only purpose is to create arrays, either with or without present keys. I'm measuring the time difference of Binary Search, which should change whether a key is present or not. Edited my question to show ticks (accidentally left milliseconds in).

Comment: @Tim, why not? When I grew sets and measured operations, it increased in this fashion. Is it just not possible?

Comment: @Hans Passant, according to the my textbook, number of operations change without there being duplicate keys (I got this to work). I just haven't gotten the time measurement to confirm this.

Comment: You don't give anybody a chance to verify your results.  But my comment certainly implied that your textbook is wrong.  As you found out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really measure it using stopwatch, especially not the difference between log2(n)+1 and log2(n)-1. Additionally, an array with 50000 (i am guessing, because you did not specify what the array creator returns) elements is a piece of cake for binary search. Milliseconds are hardly precise to capture it. Try using elapsed ticks. I doubt if you could capture such small difference with it though.

Comment: Sorry, arrayCreator returns an array of the size provided (i). I tried elapsed ticks, and it works (I made an error in the original question and said milliseconds), but it's just that there's not much of a difference between success and unsuccessful arrays. There is however a difference which perfectly matches when I'm just measuring operations and not time. The question was to ask if I was doing it right, and whether the system might affect ticks. Thanks for your answer.